# How can I stop my certificate from always revoking in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two computers. Both macs. When I have my app successfully tested and working and running from one machine, and then I push the new code and work from another, and try running the app, i get an email saying

```
You have revoked your certificate, so it is no longer valid.

Certificate: iOS Development
```

And i cannot run my code. It takes a while to get things up and running again. How can I seamlessly run and edit my xcode project without these annoying certificate errors, etc?

Comment: Are you using the same certificate on both machines or two separate ones, one for each?

Comment: same apple ID...not sure...how shall i setup separate ones assuming thats what i should do?

Comment: I use the same certificate on several computers without issues, but that's not necessarily the same thing as "same apple ID".  Is Xcode managing your certificates automatically?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how they work...but yes it is done automatically. cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add brand new Certificate or let Xcode to handle this work for you.

**Revoked means**, that you Provisioning Profiles are **no longer valid** a they have to be removed/updated with new certificate(s) to get the signing operations work.

Once you are OK with your new certificate(s) and profiles in one of your macs, use Export/Import action and transfer everything by few clicks from one mac to the second one.

**Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts**:

[image]

Profiles can be sent by email, for instance.

Comment: But you can't export only one account, effin' Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set up and there's a few things that you have to keep in mind:

- You should have the develop certificate (p12) installed in both Macs. You can look up for it on your keychain
- Never uses the `Fix Issue` button, it usually automatic revogue the certificate causing the problem you described
- Make sure you have the latest Provisioning Profile for the App you're building, it might be a problem if you have different profiles that was generate using different certificates

  I also keep both xCode logged in on the same account because it helps me to control the Provisioning Profiles and keep it up to date.

  By selecting `Automatic` on your building settings Xcode will look for the Provisioning Profile that matchs your bundle indetinfier and tries to access your certificate, so make sure you did all the steps above and you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which xCode version are you using?  In xcode 8 when you set it as automatic profile sometime it revokes, otherwise it doesn't revoke unless you tap on reset.

Comment: Did you set it as automatic..?

Comment: yes it I think so. When i go to accounts in preferences and view my account details now, it does not even give me an option to "reset" the "ios development"